# What software would be useful to create General Transit Feed Specification (GTFS)?

Tags: java, software-recommendations, php, transit, general-transit-feed-specification

I am doing a project in which i am required to create [GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference). I look at transit google developer forum which provide a format to create feed but that completely have to done by hand (we have to write text files), i was looking for a software that can help in this matter.

Comment: FME will do a good job - has a learning curve. http://blog.safe.com/2010/10/tricky-transit-data-is-transiki-the-answer/

Comment: Note FME is not free - but is extremely useful and worth the purchase.

Comment: There is some open source code that can assist: http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/

Comment: It is hard to know what you are working from, but A list that might help: http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/OtherGTFSTools . One option in PHP: http://code.google.com/p/transitdatafeeder/

Comment: thanks @Mapperz FME is a great tool , but i can't find any tutorials which are related to general transit feed creator.

Comment: How you control the feed from the GTFS is up to you. FME is good at controlling the information you need and removing what you do not require.

Comment: The format is quite easy to replicate. Recently I made my own GTFS feed from data stored in PostgreSQL; all I did was query the right data for each table, and then with a very short Python script wrote it to a text file. Took part of one day, given I already had the source data I needed in my database.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question was tagged with Java, I'd put my weight behind Conveyal's gtfs-editor, a webapp which runs on Java via the Play framework. It's pretty easy to get going if you're familiar with CLI.

https://github.com/conveyal/gtfs-editor

Answer (score 1):

You can look in the [Other GTFS tools](https://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/OtherGTFSTools) section from the old "googletransitdatafeed" on Google code.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is the service provided by AddTransit (http://addtransit.com), of which I am the manager of.

AddTransit has web based software that assists in creating the GTFS Feeds or the AddTransit team can do it for you. The web based software also supports Real Time feeds and vehicle positioning as well.

Comment: In cases like this it might be best to give full disclosure if you are an employee of or otherwise professionally connected to the software/service you are recommending. Nothing wrong with it if you are, but it helps distinguish such an answer from 'advertisement'.

Comment: ["The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Hi guys, sorry about that.  I thought the Website Url would appear below my name on the posting.  I have edited the above post to include  my role with the company,

Comment: I guess the service is not for free? Nothing about pricing found on the website at first glance.

Comment: The site doesn't allow exporting GTFS unless you pay $15 for each route. You should know this before spending an hour on sketching routes.

Answer (score -2):

GTFS editor - www.mobilibus.com.br
Create acount - http://editor.mobilibus.com/create-account.html